# Flask + Scrapy: How I can prevent 403 error on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a web scraping app hosted by heroku. I always get 403 errors on heroku, but page works fine if I run the code locally.

How can I prevent these 403 errors from happening at all? Relevant code as follows:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy
import json
import sqlite3


class Ratemds(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'ratemds'
allowed_domains = ['ratemds.com']

custom_settings = {
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.50747 OPRGX/60.0.3255.50747',
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2.5,
    'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY' : True,
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 1,
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY' : 3,
}

def start_requests(self): 
    settings = ''

    with open('ratemds.json', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.read():
            settings += line

    settings = json.loads(settings)

    if settings['state'] == []:
        for specialty in settings['specialty']:
            yield scrapy.Request('https://www.ratemds.com/best-doctors/?specialty=%s' % specialty, callback=self.profile_link)

def profile_link(self, response):
    for a in response.css('.search-item-doctor-link'):
        yield response.follow(a, callback=self.profile)

def profile(self, response):

    item =  {
            'url': response.request.url,
            'Image': response.css('.doctor-profile-image::attr(src)').get(),
            'First_and_Last_Name': response.css('h1::text').get(),
            'Position': response.css('.col-sm-6 .search-item-info~ .search-item-info+ .search-item-info span::text').getall(),
            'Reviews': response.css('.star-rating-count span span::text').get(),
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Ratemds)
process.start()
```